# how to find standard deviation of sampling distribution without knowing population parameter σ

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, sampling

Standard deviation of sampling distribution is given as σ/sqrt(n). But usually the population parameter σ will be unknown.

1. In that case, how do we calcuate the standard deviation of sampling distribution (lets say while working on hypothesis testing) ?
2. One possibility is that we take a large number of samples N (each of size k) and then compute the standard deviation from these values. Is that practicle OR will it be possible only for such large values of N where possibly N*k might be approaching the population size ?
3. Practically how this problem of finding the standard deviation of sampling distribution is solved when we have say few samples (each of size k) & want to go ahead with hypothesis testing which requires knowing the standard deviation of sampling distribution ?

Also if someone can point any relevant links to understand this better, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Usually we just estimate the population variance with the sample variance and plug our estimate into the standard error.  So if $s^2$ is the sample variance then we use $s$ in our estimate of the standard error.  This approach is legitimized by Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Thanks @DemetriPananos . I have few related questions:
1) If we actually compute the sample variance (with s as the estimate of standard error) then what is the minimum number(n) of samples (each of size k) required to compute the correct variance ? Just like we say that for k ~ 30 we get the gaussian distribution. Do we have any such value for n which gives a good approximation of variance ? 
2) Also, i tried to go through slutsky's theorem but still not able to understand on how that helps to explain the above questions. Please let me know if you can explain on how this theorem helps here.

Comment: @DemetriPananos : can you please provide some info on how Slutsky's theorem helps here. May be you can add the details as an answer (rather than a comment), so that i can accept as well. Thanks.